# How can we capture traffic under WiFi AP connected with an WAN router?

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis

My PC is connected to the internet via an WiFi access point.
The AP is connected to the router that provides global IP address.
In our network, some of the PCs (Say PCs1) are directly connected to the router through L2 switch with LAN cables. 
The other PCs (say PCs2) including mine are connected to the internet via WiFi AP.

```
[WAN] ---[Router] --- [L2 Switch]--- [PCs1]

            |
             ---------[Wifi-AP] ---- [PCs2]
```

- How can I monitor all the traffic under Wifi-AP?
  I can only see the traffic to/from my PC and broadcasting to/from others in PCs2.
- Is it possible to capture traffic of PCs1 from PCs2 with Wireshark?
- Is the only thing to do so capture the traffic through the router?

NOTE: I'm not using TAP. Having my PC being monitor mode, I think wifi-AP allows us to see all traffic of PCs2 via Wireshark.